# "He took a picture of himself TO school." What is the meaning of TO

Tags: sentence-meaning

On **Light verb (wikipedia)** page I found a sentence:

> He took a picture of himself **to** school.

Does it mean the same as: *He took a picture of himself on the way to school.*

I am confused, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: "He took, to school, a picture of himself."  The preposition is in an odd place.

Answer (score 4):

It means that he had a picture of himself, and he took (brought) it to school.

*Take* here is being used in the sense of "to bring or carry" (see 15a [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)), not in the sense of "to create a photograph" (11b3).

You should parse the sentence as

> he took (a picture (of himself)) to school

not

> he ((took a picture) of himself) to school

Comment: +1   To clarify, if you want to specify the other meaning you would say *"He took a picture of himself **on his way** to school"*